# How to code multiple values field in Views PHP?

Tags: 7, views

I need help setting up ViewsPHP to evaluate 3 pieces of data? (I barely know any PHP)

### ViewFields

I have a View with three embedded Viewfields:

**Node count**
$row->view
[views_field_view_view]

**Time ago (1 unit)**
$row->view_1
[views_field_view_view_1]

**Success rate**
$row->view_2
[views_field_view_view_2]

### Value code

In the Value Code text area I want to call all the values. I currently have:

```
return $data;
```

### Output code

In the Output Code I want to do something like this:

```
<?php
if ($row->view >= 5 AND $row->view_1 >= 5 AND $row->view_2 >= 80) { 
    echo "Amazing person";
}
elseif ($row->view >= 3 AND $row->view_1 >= 3 AND $row->view_2 >= 70) { 
    echo "Good person";
} 
elseif ($row->view >= 1 AND $row->view_2 >= 60) { 
    echo "Interesting person";
}
else {
    echo "Content needed";
}
?>
```

It's only outputting "Content needed" so what have I done wrong?

EDIT: Updating to 7.x-2.x-dev makes this work.

Answer (score 0):

Structurally, your code looks fine, it's probably because

`$row->view` = `<div id="views-view--view-name"><div>5</div></div>` basically the 5 has HTML tags around it.

so `<div id="views-view--view-name"><div>5</div></div>` does not equal 5

You can use the PHP [strip_tags()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp) function to get rid off the tags.

```
if (strip_tags($row->view) >= 5 AND strip_tags($row->view_1) >= 5 AND strip_tags($row->view_2) >= 80) {
```

So try this:

```
<?php

$a = strip_tags($row->view);
$b = strip_tags($row->view_1);
$c = strip_tags($row->view_2);

if ($a >= 5 AND $b >= 5 AND $c >= 80) { 
    echo "Amazing person";
}
elseif ($a >= 3 AND $b >= 3 AND $c >= 70) { 
    echo "Good person";
} 
elseif ($a >= 1 AND $c >= 60) { 
    echo "Interesting person";
}
else {
    echo "Content needed";
}
?>
```

**PS**: no need to have anything for value code <strike>`return $data;`</strike>.

Comment: Maybe it needs more than just strip_tags to parse the ViewField because I'm getting crazy results. EQUAL TO works but LESS THAN does not.  $a = 3 is true, $a <= 3 is passed over even though the string is 3.

Comment: @JohnD `$a = 3 is true` equal to needs to be two equals signs `$a == 3` because if you use only 1 equal sign, it sets the variable to 3, rather than evaluate/test to see if it equals 3, which will always return true.

Comment: @JohnD when you `echo $row->view;` what gets printed? just a number or do you see more stuff?

Comment: `echo $row->view;` prints nothing, but `print_r ($data);
` prints this `stdClass Object ( [users_name] => Ben [uid] => 140 [users_created] => 1437618401 [views_field_view_view] =>
3
[views_field_view_view_1] =>
1 year
[views_field_view_view_2] =>
64
)`

Comment: @JohnD "`echo $row->view;` prints nothing" well then that's your problem, your view is empty. `$data` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Right, looks like global:View fields are not loaded in Views PHP.  [...does not work well with Views PHP](http://blog.hsl.virginia.edu/drupalpress/views-field-view-what-works-and-what-irks/) and [more](https://www.drupal.org/node/1677520). Time to construct the view without Global Views Field View.

Comment: @JohnD when you add the view as a field, does it show? Does the view that you're adding as a field have a contextual filter?

Comment: Yes, the View Fields output on their own as they should. Yes, they had a contextual filter operating OK. Now I have reconstructed the view without embedding View Fields and my conditional PHP is working but `echo $row->view;` still shows nothing, not to worry. Just need to get my User Date Created field to print.